# What's the exact meaning of iota?

Tags: go, iota

In the code below:

```
const (
    signature uint32 = 0xae3179fb
    dhkxGroup = 2

    ReplySuccessful byte = iota
    ReplyBufferCorrupted
    ReplyDecryptFailed
    ReplySessionExpired
    ReplyPending
)
```

`ReplySuccessful` is compiled to `2`, while I think it should definitly be **ZERO**. If I move `signature` and `dhkxGroup` below `ReplyPending`, then `ReplySuccessful` becomes 0.

Why is this?

PS. To me, the only "benefit" of using iota is that you can ommit the value assigned to later constants, so that you can easily modify/insert new values.  However, if iota is not **FIXED** to zero, it could cause big problem especially in doing things like communication protocols.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Iota) defines iota's usage in Go (emphasis added):

> Within a constant declaration, the predeclared identifier iota represents successive untyped integer constants. **Its value is the index of the respective [ConstSpec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#ConstSpec) in that constant declaration, starting at zero.**

Note that the index is relative to the `ConstSpec`, basically meanining the current `const` block.

Of particular interest is probably the example provided:

> ```golang
> const (
>   a = 1 << iota  // a == 1  (iota == 0)
>   b = 1 << iota  // b == 2  (iota == 1)
>   c = 3          // c == 3  (iota == 2, unused)
>   d = 1 << iota  // d == 8  (iota == 3)
> )
> ```

Notice line 3 (iota value 2) is unused.  You have essentially the same, with two unused values coming first.

What you probably meant in your code is:

```golang
const (
    signature uint32 = 0xae3179fb
    dhkxGroup = 2
)

const (
    ReplySuccessful byte = iota
    ReplyBufferCorrupted
    ReplyDecryptFailed
    ReplySessionExpired
    ReplyPending
)
```

See it [on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dLIVJ740cmV)

Comment: Thanks. The definition of iota is now clear to me, however, I still don't know **why** it is designed like this.  I'll open a new question.